# element hover not working properly in css3 fade effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a simple project where a single block element hover will show 4x zoom element. I did it through pure css and css3 transition. See the jsfiddle demo . There will be four element , each has different hover element. But when I hover on it only one hover element is showing though it is not associate with that block or element.

Check the demo to make yourself an opinion.

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.main a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.main a .child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: gray;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.main a:hover .child {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="child">
      <h4>1.Text</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="child">
      <h4>2.Text</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="child">
      <h4>3.Text</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="child">
      <h4>4.Text</h4>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

[Demo project on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zinannadeem/phmypx9v/6/)

Important note: if i use display none or block in hover instate the css3 transition then it is working fine, But i need the fade effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is that the four .child element is showed when hover on a element, but only the last .child is visible, to resolve this isue use **visibility** property instead **display**:

https://jsfiddle.net/f9m1mnce/

```css
.main{
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 overflow:hidden 
}
.main a{
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%; 
 float:left;
}
.main a > .child{
 position: absolute; 
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
 background: gray;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;     
}
.main a:hover > .child{
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in .2;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in .2 ;
 -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in .2;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in .2;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in .2; 
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
 zoom: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <a href="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <div class="child">
   <h4>1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h4>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <div class="child">
   <h4>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h4>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <div class="child">
   <h4>3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h4>
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <div class="child">
   <h4>4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h4>
  </div>
 </a>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A absolute element is associated to its parent relative element, in your demo in your demo you need to set position relative to **a tag**

```
.main a{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%; 
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **[`::before`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="content-ul">
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" titulo="Lorem 1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" titulo="Lorem 2">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" titulo="Lorem 3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" titulo="Lorem 4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content-ul{
    display: block;
    width: 340px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content-ul li,#content-ul li a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content-ul li{
    margin: 10px 10px ;
}
#content-ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#content-ul li a img{
    border-radius: 4px;

}
#content-ul li a:before{
    visibility: hidden;
    content: attr(titulo);
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 250px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(0,0,50,.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;

    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;

}
#content-ul li a:hover::before{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in; 
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1.0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**<kbd>[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kae1ocon/1/)</kbd>**

---

Here an update based on your code:

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="main">
    <a href="" content="1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </a>
    <a href="" content="2Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </a>
    <a href="" content="3Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </a>
    <a href="" content="4Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    overflow:hidden
}
.main a{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%; 
    float:left;
}       
.main a:before{
    visibility: hidden;
    content: attr(content);
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 250px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(0,0,50,.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
.main a:hover::before{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in; 
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1.0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**<kbd>[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qf26a2vn/1/)</kbd>**

Comment: Its only a suggest. I will update my answer, with a posible solution to his code